# How to get value of each element from this program

Tags: c

In this program I have been asked to use only pointer in the void function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "power.c"
#define SIZE 20
int count = 0;

void test(int  *n, int *o) {
    long long sum = 0, temp;
    int remainder, digits = 0;
    int i;
    int a[SIZE];
    temp = *n;
    while (temp != 0) {
        digits++;
        temp = temp/10;
    } 

    temp = *n;

    while (temp != 0) {
        remainder = temp%10;
        sum = sum + power(remainder, digits);
        temp = temp/10;
    }    

    if (*n == sum)
    { 
        count++;
        a[count] = *n;
    }
    o = a;
    for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
        printf("*******%i,%d\n",i,o[i]);
    }
}
```

and here is the test bench

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20 
int main () {
    int c, a, b;
    int *x;
    int *y;      
    int i;
    a = 2 ;
    b = 1000;
    //b = 345678910;
    for (c = a; c <= b; c++) {
         x = &c;
         test(x,y);     
    }
}
```

it prints out something like

*******1,2
*******2,3
*******12,407

These values are correct however I'd like to print every element of y after calling test in the test bench and expect these values are similar to the above values but I don't know how to do it. I am seeking help from you.

Regards
Tony

Comment: At the end of function `test` you are setting `o = a;` as if you hope that the local (automatic) array `a[]` will find it's way back to `y` in `main`. It won't, it is just overwriting the *copy of* the pointer which was passed as an argument, which on return will be discarded. Even if you *do* pass `a[]` back to `main` correctly, that array will have gone out of scope.

Comment: try `static int a[SIZE];` in your test function...

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=count;i++)` is wrong, arrays are indexed from `0` to `size-1`, so `for(i=0;i<count;i++)`

Comment: Same issue here `count++; a[count] = *n;` you should increment `count` afterwards, not before.

Comment: the storage class for the global variable 'int count' not defined. auto storage class does not apply by default to global variables.

Comment: `int count = 0;` must be moved *inside the function*. On second and other calls to `test`, `count` will be out of range of the array index.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't print the values **after** calling `test`. The reason is that `a` goes out of scope when `test` returns. In other words - `y` is simply not pointing to valid memory and any attempt to access it may cause a program crash.

You have the following problems:

1) `y` is pointing to invalid memory when `test`returns (as mentioned above)

2) `count` shall not be global

3) `count` should start from zero instead of one

That would look:

```
// int count = 0; Don't make it global

void test(int  *n, int *o, int* cnt)
{
    ....
    int count = 0;
    int* a = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    ....

    if (*n == sum)
    { 
        a[count] = *n;  // Switch the two statements to index from zero
        count++;
    }
    o = a;
    *cnt = count;       // Return the value of count

    for(i=0;i<count;i++){  // Notice this change - start index from zero
        printf("*******%i,%d\n",i,o[i]);
    }
}

int main () {
    int count;
    ....

    test(x, y, &count);  // Pass a pointer to count

    // Now print y
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        printf("*******%d\n", y[i]);
    }
    free(y);  // Release memory when done with it
```

An alternative to dynamic memory allocation is to declare the array in main:

```
int main () {
    int count;
    int y[SIZE];
    ....

    test(x, y, &count);  // Pass a pointer to count

    // Now print y
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        printf("*******%d\n", y[i]);
    }
```

and in the function just use `y` directly instead of the variable `a`